# How to define and initialize two dimension string array in Julia?

Tags: julia

in Java a 2 dimension string array can be defined and initialized as follows:

```
String[][] a = {{"a","b"}, {"c","d"}, {"e","f"}};
```

Please help me in explicitly defining and assigning values in Julia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use (you can find the details [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#man-array-concatenation-1)):

```
julia> a = ["a" "b"; "c" "d"; "e" "f"]
3×2 Array{String,2}:
 "a"  "b"
 "c"  "d"
 "e"  "f"
```

or

```
julia> a = ["a" "b"
            "c" "d"
            "e" "f"]
3×2 Array{String,2}:
 "a"  "b"
 "c"  "d"
 "e"  "f"
```

and you can assign the value by

```
julia> a[1,2] = "new string"
"new string"

julia> a
3×2 Array{String,2}:
 "a"  "new string"
 "c"  "d"
 "e"  "f"
```

in a similar way you can access it:

```
julia> a[1,2]
"new string"
```

Comment: Sir, Whether it is matrix or 2 dimensional array?

Comment: This is a `Matrix`. But in Julia 2 dimensional array is a matrix. Did you want a nested `Vector` of `Vectors` instead of a `Matrix`? In this case write `[["a","b"], ["c","d"], ["e","f"]]`

Comment: Sir  whether the following expression is type safe definition and explicit assignment? Matrix{String}(3,2)=["a" "b"; "c" "d"; "e" "f"];

Comment: This is an invalid code. This would be valid `m = Matrix{String}(undef,3,2)` and then you could write `m .= ["a" "b"; "c" "d"; "e" "f"]`.

Comment: Sir, it is a 3x2 matrix of strings. What this undef refers to?

Comment: That you do not initialize it.